# Compare number of instances in a column for two different dates in SAS

Tags: date, sas, compare, proc

I have the following dataset (`items`) with transactions on any date and amount paid on the next business day.

The amount paid for each id on the next business day is $10 for the ids whose `rate` is `>5`

My task is to compare the number of instances where `rate > 5` are in line with amount paid on the next business day (This will have a standard `code 121`)

For instance, there are four instances with `rate > 5` on `4/14/2017'  - The amount`$40 (4*10)`is paid on`4/17/2017`

```
Date       id  rate code    batch
4/14/2017   1   12  100     A1
4/14/2017   1    2  101     A1
4/14/2017   1   13  101     A1
4/14/2017   1   10  100     A1
4/14/2017   1   10  100     A1
4/17/2017   1   40  121 
4/20/2017   2   12  100     A1
4/20/2017   2   2   101     A1
4/20/2017   2   3   101     A1
4/20/2017   2   10  100     A1
4/20/2017   2   10  100     A1
4/21/2017   2   30  121
```

`My code`

```
proc sql;
   create table items2 as select 
     count(id) as id_count,
     (case when code='121' then rate/10 else 0 end) as rate_count
    from items
    group by date,id;
quit;
```

This has not yielded the desired result and the challenge I have here is to check the transaction dates (`4/14/2017` and `4/20/2017`) and next business day dates (`4/17/2017`,`4/21/2017`).

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

LAG function will do the trick here. As we can use lagged values to create the condition we want without having to use the rate>5 condition.

Here is the solution:-

```
Data items;
set items;

Lag_dt=LAG(Date);
Lag_id=LAG(id);
Lag_rate=LAG(rate);

if ((id=lag_id) and (code=121) and (Date>lag_dt)) then rate_count=(rate/lag_rate);
else rate_count=0;

Drop lag_dt lag_id lag_rate;

run;
```

Hope this helps.